# Посчитать количество букв T,t в слове

Tags: c++

Функция принимает строку (как массив символов) и возвращает количество больших и маленьких букв ‘T’ в этом массиве (например “Te twd rT” дает 3).
**В задании необходимо написать функцию которая принимает строку.**
Делал вот так:

```
include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
 int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char s[1000];
    cout << "\n Введите слово или предложение на Английском языке с буквами t и нажмите Enter:\n";
    cin.get(s,1000);
    for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (s[i] == 't') sum++;
    if (s[i] == 'T') sum++;
}
    cout << "\n Общее число букв t:\n" << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: она уже написана `cin.get(s,1000);`. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Давайте посмотрим... Где именно вы выполняете требуемое? Я эти строки выделяю комментарием.

```
include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char s[1000];
    cout << "\n Введите слово или предложение на Английском языке с буквами t и нажмите Enter:\n";
    cin.get(s,1000);
    // Вот здесь вы получили строку и считаете...
    // Предусловие: водная строка s
    for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 't') sum++;
        if (s[i] == 'T') sum++;
    }
    // Вот здесь - закончили считать
    // Постусловие: результат в переменной sum
    cout << "\n Общее число букв t:\n" << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. если бы у вас была функция `int countT(const char s[])`, то код бы выглядел просто

```
    cin.get(s,1000);
    sum = countT(s);
    cout << "\n Общее число букв t:\n" << sum;
```

Давайте теперь вынесем эти строки в отдельную функцию.

```
int countT(const char s[])
{
    // Переменная sum осталась за пределами функции. Значит, ее надо добавить...
    int sum = 0;
    // Вот здесь вы получили строку и считаете...
    // Предусловие: водная строка s
    for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 't') sum++;
        if (s[i] == 'T') sum++;
    }
    // Вот здесь - закончили считать
    // Постусловие: результат в переменной sum 
    // Значит, именно ее надо вернуть!
    return sum;
}
```

Осталось разместить эту функцию в коде перед `main`, чтобы ее можно было вызвать. Итак, весь код теперь имеет вид:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int countT(const char s[])
{
    // Переменная sum осталась за пределами функции. Значит, ее надо добавить...
    int sum = 0;
    // Вот здесь вы получили строку и считаете...
    // Предусловие: водная строка s
    for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 't') sum++;
        if (s[i] == 'T') sum++;
    }
    // Вот здесь - закончили считать
    // Постусловие: результат в переменной sum
    // Значит, именно ее надо вернуть!
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    char s[1000];
    cout << "\n Введите слово или предложение на Английском языке с буквами t и нажмите Enter:\n";
    cin.get(s,1000);
    sum = countT(s);
    cout << "\n Общее число букв t:\n" << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Что здесь было сложного? если, конечно, код написан вами, а не списан у кого-то без понимания...

Comment: А зачем поощрять `for (int i = strlen(s)-1; i >= 0; i--)`? Может все же лучше `for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)`?

Comment: @avp Можно и вовсе `for (int i = strlen(s); i --> 0;)` :) Цель была не в оптимизации/исправлении, я даже `else` не стал дописывать, не говоря уж о `toupper`, например...